# Creating duplicate rows and changing the words in the row - R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of train stations that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+
|site                |
+--------------------+
|NRL North Station   |
|Nrl North Station   |
|ECL East Stn        |
|Ecl East Stn        |
```

And I'd like to change it to the following:

```
+--------------------+
|site                |
+--------------------+
|NRL North Station   |
|NRL North Stn       |
|Nrl North Station   |
|Nrl North Stn       |
|ECL East Stn        |
|ECL East Station    |
|Ecl East Stn        |
|Ecl East Station    |
```

Basically the logic is to

1. create duplicates of rows where in the duplicate, "Station" is converted to "Stn"
2. create duplicates of rows where in the duplicate, "Stn" is converted to "Station"

So that we have two copies of one original entry, one which ends in "Station" and one which ends in "Stn".

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mgsub::mgsub` to perform the replacement and bind the data to original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number())

df1 %>%
  mutate(site = mgsub::mgsub(site,c('Station', 'Stn'), c('Stn', 'Station'))) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1) %>%
  arrange(row)

#               site row
#1     NRL North Stn   1
#2 NRL North Station   1
#3     Nrl North Stn   2
#4 Nrl North Station   2
#5  ECL East Station   3
#6      ECL East Stn   3
#7  Ecl East Station   4
#8      Ecl East Stn   4
```

I have included an additional column which is row number of the data so that we can maintain the original order of data. You can remove the column with `select(-row)` if you don't need.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(site = c("NRL North Station", "Nrl North Station", 
"ECL East Stn", "Ecl East Stn")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```